# Nested table of 100% height exceeds screen in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

Here's a piece of code to illustrates my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
            table {border-collapse:collapse;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width='100%' height='100%'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    header
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign='top' height='100%'>
                    <table width='100%' height='100%' bgcolor='red'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>test</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page that I'm currently building has a header and a table below it, table must take all the vertical space available but must not exceed the screen height. Code above works fine in FF/Chrome/Safari but in IE nested table does exceeds the screen height exactly by the height of header above thus causing vertical scrollbar which is an undesired behavior.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Which version of IE? None of them work the same as each other or the other modern browsers.

Comment: I'm using IE9 for tests.

Comment: The best way to fix this would be not to use tables. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to have to fill the whole available space?

Comment: That's a design requirement of an application I'm building. I'm using nested table because it's content is tabular data.

Answer (score 2):

IE is not good about calculating heights in tables.  In this case, it's setting the cell height to 100% of the body and html rather than its parent container.
Easiest thing to do, but also an ugly hack, is to put

`<!–- For Internet Explorer -–>` on a line above `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

This will force IE into quirksmode and should render properly for your case.  You may have to restart IE rather than simply refresh the page after adding the comment.

Comment: I've just tried and this solution works but removing doctype causes a lot of other problems. Is it really the only possible way?

Comment: For this case, it's the easy way to deal with IE.  It looks like no matter what you try, you will be juggling IE bugs.  Although you said CSS layout was not an option, that is what I would do.

Comment: CSS layout is definitely an option if it can help. Maybe you can outline some CSS techiques I could use to get similar layout?

Comment: Check out some CSS liquid layout tutorials.  Based on your code, it seems close to what you want to do.  Look into CSS top and bottom properties as well.  I can tell there is much missing info for your use case, so I'm not sure how to direct you to any more precise information.  Good luck!

Comment: @Anton: In order to recommend CSS techniques, you need to explain what you want to achieve (as I asked in my other comment). Currently your table just fills the background with another color, which you could do by just setting the the background color of the body. Explain in detail **why** you need to fill the whole screen and it's easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
html, body {height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

to

```
html, body {height:100%;margin:0;padding:0; overflow-y: hidden;}
```

It will remove the vertical scroll-bar from the IE (or any web browser)

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. Using this approach some part of content on bottom will just become inaccessible in IE.

Comment: @Anton : Is that happening ? Did you try it ? Please post the exact o/p, what exactly you want ?

Comment: It's happening if content in nested table is bottom-aligned and it certainly will happen in case when table contains more content then browser window can hold without scrollbar.