# Height 100% issue in IE10. Works in Quirks mode in IE and all other browers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please see the following page:

http://www.judsondesigns.com/Demos/jscroller/index.html

If you notice in IE, it is causing scrolling. Every other browser is ok. Why is IE causing the scroll? How can I fix this?

Thanks

Judson

here is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
html, body{ 

    height:100%; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

 }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="display:table; width: 100%; height:100%;">
<div style="display: table-row; background: red">test</div>
<div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell; height:100%; width:100%;overflow: hidden ">
            <div style=" height:100%; width:100%; overflow:hidden; background: #06F">test123
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row; background: red;">test</div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And a picture normal IE10 mode:
[image: Screen Shot of scrolling issue in IE]

and in Quirks mode( how I need it to look )
[image: Screen Shot of Quirks mode in IE]

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)...

Comment: I have added more detail to this. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You should set a negative `margin-bottom` on the `div` containing the `test123` text of a value higher than the height of the `table-row` at the bottom. You could set it to `-100%` to be safe, that will fix it in IE, and won't break it in any other browsers.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p4uSn/2/show/)</kbd>

Comment: This is the closest I have gotten. Thanks. However, When I try to add an absolute positioned div as seen below, the bottom gets cut off in IE. ANy idea on how to avoid that? You should see a "fake" white border around the whole box. http://www.judsondesigns.com/Demos/jscroller/index.html

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15294575/1846192) is the underlying issue with IE, I don't think there's a fix for that (the untested fix mentioned doesn't work). You could remove the `<!DOCTYPE>` or [add a line above it as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5369564) to force IE into quirks mode. Or you could change to not using table layout, but my guess is you want the table-layout because the middle `div` is meant to scale down when any of the other `div`'s change in height, and I don't think that will work without table layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table; max-height: 100%;">
<div style="background: red; height: 2%; display: table-row;">test</div>
<div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 96%; overflow: hidden; display: table-cell; max-height: 100%; background-color: blue;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: inherit; color: green; display: table;">test123456
 asdfasdfasdf           </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div style="background: red; height: 2%; display: table-row;">test</div></div>
```

this worked for me

Comment: So how can I make this where it will work in standard ie10 mode? 96.2 won't work because when I resize its not really 96.2 and suggestions?

Comment: That's not a solution to the problem, the whole point is that I need that div that you took the height away from to be able to expand 100% of the table cell. So any ideas?

Comment: So, I tried you code like this, but the problem with the 96% is that if the header or footer expands based on the content in them ,the 96% becomes invalid. Any other ideas? It makes no sense that all the other browsers are handling this perfectly except IE10. Whats the common denominator? Or better yet what are the other browsers doing that IE is not?

Comment: it's working for me - so I don't know what to say it's not just IE 10 it's all IE's your essentially using tables when you display divs as tables I'm sure IE even the new version hasn't updated the way they display tables because people only really use tables to display table/spreadsheet data - not sure why you are using display table - this would be much easier using regular divs display as block elements not as table elements

Comment: you could use position:fixed for the top and bottom divs and dow whatever in the middle

Comment: The whole reason for the tables is to allow the "rest of height" fix. Its seems the table approach is the only way to accomplish filling the rest of the page height in this case between the header and footer by using table cells and putting 100% height up the chain. IE is not liking it for some reason though :(